# AngularJS, How to correctly modify http headers in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am hoping an Angular guru can point me in the right direction.  When using a factory in the format below, how do I modify the header for POST so that:

```
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'?
```

The code:

```
var tableModule = angular.module('theApp', ['ui-rangeSlider','ngScrollbar']);

tableModule.factory('Services', ['$http',
function($http) {
    return {
        get : function($path, callback) {
            return $http.get($path).success(callback);      
        },
        post : function($path, $data, callback) {
            return $http.post($path, $data).success(callback);
        }   
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use the third *config* argument to [`$http.post`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)...

```
post: function(path, data) {
    return $http.post(path, data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why did you remove the callback?

Comment: @nodoze just habit. I prefer to work with the promise objects themselves. The main point of my answer was to show you how to pass headers

Comment: well I think this did the trick, thanks Phil.  it didnt fix my larger issue, but it appears that headers are passed.  my larger angular question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226519/accessing-post-data-in-python-with-cgi-fieldstorage-using-angularjs

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like this earlier. The method would look like

```
$scope.update = function (user) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://mytestserver.com/that/does/not/exists',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                var postData = [];
                for (var prop in data)
                postData.push(encodeURIComponent(prop) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[prop]));
                return postData.join("&");
            },
            data: user
        });
    }
```

Also see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/doLhmgL6/